# How do I guarantee that I get 1000 rows from a SELECT query? MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Questions with answers that instruct on the use of LIMIT are not working for my situation, but it could be I misunderstand the limitations and imperfections of LIMIT. Or, maybe I am doing the query wrong, which makes this question legitimate.

I have a table called "child_pages" which contains a field called "url", the value of which is a url that should be scraped. Upon scraping the page belonging to that url, the resulting content html is stored in a field called "content". The child_pages table has 200,000 records.

The table also has a "scanned" and "processed" field, both of them tinyint so I can say "1" = yes, this row was scanned, and "1", this row was processed.

One script, which I have set up as a local service (Windows) will read through the child_pages table and read the value from the url field, then perform the scrape, and finally store the resulting html into the content field. When this is done, the "scanned" field will be marked "1".

Now another script is also running separately, which queries the child_pages table looking for all records that are scanned='1', but processed='0'. From that result set I'm going to read the html value of the content field from the non-processed records, finally doing something with the data I extract from the "content" field html.

This is my query:

```
$sql = "SELECT id,content FROM child_pages WHERE scanned='1' AND processed='0' LIMIT 1000";
```

I've noticed that the processing is extremely slow. I get 1 to a few records processed every five seconds. How can that be, I thought, when I'm selecting 1000 rows at a time?

So I outputted a counter of loops inside the while loop, and I find it doesn't return $counted = 1000, but rather something like $counted = 60.

I have queried the child_pages table and found that 95% of the records are processed='0', so there are plenty of records to accommodate a LIMIT 1000.

Is there a way to force my query to return 1000 rows?

Full query loop:

```
$start = "<div id=\"detailtable\">";
$stop = "</table></td></tr></table></div>";
$sql = "SELECT id,content FROM child_pages WHERE scanned='1' AND processed='0' LIMIT 1000";
$stmt = $db->query($sql);
$new = 0;
$lookedat = 0;
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
  $lookedat++;
  $content = $row['content'];
  $cid = $row['id'];
  $mark1 = strpos($content,$start);
  $mark2 = strpos($content,$stop);
  //echo $mark1 . ", " . $mark2;
  $segment = substr( $content,$mark1, ($mark2 - $mark1) + strlen($stop) );
  $doc = new simple_html_dom($segment);
  if ( ! is_null($doc->find("div[id=detailtable]", 0)) ){
    $detailtable = $doc->find("div[id=detailtable]", 0);
    if(count($detailtable) == 1){
        $e = $detailtable->children();
        $children = $e[0]->find('.data');
        $count = 0;
        $insert['processed_thru']       = trim($children[0]->plaintext);
        $insert['document_number_j']    = trim($children[1]->plaintext);
        $insert['status']               = trim($children[2]->plaintext);
        $insert['case_number']          = trim($children[3]->plaintext);
        $insert['name_of_court']        = trim($children[4]->plaintext);
        $insert['file_date']            = trim($children[5]->plaintext);
        $insert['date_of_entry']        = trim($children[6]->plaintext);
        $insert['expiration_date']      = trim($children[7]->plaintext);
        $insert['amount_due']           = trim(str_replace("$","",$children[8]->plaintext));
        $insert['interest_rate']        = trim($children[9]->plaintext);
        $insert['plaintiff']            = trim($children[10]->plaintext);

        $insert['defendant'] = "";

        for($iii=11;$iii<count($children) ;$iii++){
            $insert['defendant'] .= trim($children[$iii]->plaintext);
        }

        if( $insert['status'] !== "TERMINATED" &&
            strpos($insert['plaintiff'],"STATE OF FLORIDA") == false &&
            strpos($insert['plaintiff'],"DEPARTMENT OF REVENUE") == false &&
            strpos($insert['plaintiff'],"DEPARTMENT OF ENVIRONMENTAL PROTECTION") == false){

            //net elements here

            /*echo "<pre>";
            print_r($insert);*/

            // table: cases2 columns:  id,processed_thru,document_number_j,status,case_number,name_of_court,file_date,date_of_entry,expiration_date,amount_due,interest_rate,plaintiff,defendant
            $colstring = "processed_thru,document_number_j,status,case_number,name_of_court,file_date,date_of_entry,expiration_date,amount_due,interest_rate,plaintiff,defendant";
            $prepareColString = ":processed_thru,:document_number_j,:status,:case_number,:name_of_court,:file_date,:date_of_entry,:expiration_date,:amount_due,:interest_rate,:plaintiff,:defendant";
            $table = "cases";

            foreach($insert as $k=>$v){
                ${"$k"} = trim(preg_replace( '/\h+/', ' ', $v ));
            }

            $stmt2 = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO $table ($colstring) VALUES ($prepareColString)");
            $stmt2->bindParam(':document_number_j', $document_number_j);
            $stmt2->bindParam(':processed_thru', $processed_thru);
            $stmt2->bindParam(':status', $status);
            $stmt2->bindParam(':case_number', $case_number);
            $stmt2->bindParam(':name_of_court', $name_of_court);
            $stmt2->bindParam(':file_date', $file_date);
            $stmt2->bindParam(':date_of_entry', $date_of_entry);
            $stmt2->bindParam(':expiration_date', $expiration_date);
            $stmt2->bindParam(':amount_due', $amount_due);
            $stmt2->bindParam(':interest_rate', $interest_rate);
            $stmt2->bindParam(':plaintiff', $plaintiff);
            $stmt2->bindParam(':defendant', $defendant);
            $stmt2->execute();

            $new++;
        }
    }
  }
  $processed = 1;
  $stmt3 = $db->prepare("UPDATE child_pages SET processed=:processed WHERE id=:id");
  $stmt3->bindParam(':id', $cid);
  $stmt3->bindParam(':processed', $processed);
  $stmt3->execute();
}
```

Accessory data:

```
RECORDS SCANNED : 60

NEW CASE RECORDS : 8

COMPUTATIONS IN ms : 422
SYSTEM CALLS IN ms : 15

Total execution time in seconds: 129.66131019592
```

Code that outputs the accessory data:
(these are placed at top of script)

```
// At start of script
$time_start = microtime(true);
$rustart = getrusage();

function rutime($ru, $rus, $index) {
    return ($ru["ru_$index.tv_sec"]*1000 + intval($ru["ru_$index.tv_usec"]/1000))
 -  ($rus["ru_$index.tv_sec"]*1000 + intval($rus["ru_$index.tv_usec"]/1000));
}


echo "<p>RECORDS SCANNED : $lookedat </p>";
echo "<p>NEW CASE RECORDS : $new </p>";

$ru = getrusage();

echo "<p>COMPUTATIONS IN ms : " . rutime($ru, $rustart, "utime") . "</p>";
echo "SYSTEM CALLS IN ms : " . rutime($ru, $rustart, "stime") . "</p>";

// Anywhere else in the script
echo '<p>Total execution time in seconds: ' . (microtime(true) - $time_start) . "</p>";
```

Comment: Perhaps ask the right question: why is the query so slow?

Comment: Surely you need to `order by` something to make the `limit` meaningful. And "I have queried the child_pages table and found that 95% of the records are processed='0'," - yes, and how many have `processed = 0 AND scanned = 1`, which is what the query in question does? Anyway, what `while` loop? Post all the relevant code.

Comment: How much time processing of each page/rows take? Does your script get executed successfully?

Comment: There is not enough information here but that query *will* return 1000 records if there are 1000 records that meet the `WHERE` conditions. The SQL query is not the issue unless as @underscore_d mentioned there arent many records with `processed = 0 AND scanned = 1`.

Comment: @underscore_d I don't see why I need to order by. I don't care about the order. All I care is that I'm getting records where scanned='1' and processed='0'. The while loop loops over the result set of the query I gave in my example, but I can add that in the question if it helps you to visualize.

Comment: The speed will likely be controlled by what you do in the loop that retrieves these rows. If you are doing the SCRAPE inside that loop then that would definitely explain the speed. Have you looked at the MYSQL log to see if you are getting timedout in some way?

Comment: Hi @Alok, actually, I have that data. I will add to the question text.

Comment: @InfiniteLoop If you remove PHP from the equation and just run the exact query - _with_ `scanned = 1` unlike your previous comparison - how many rows does it return?

Comment: Hi @RiggsFolly, I am monitoring the script and it processes without timing out. There is a lot going on within the loop, but it seems like the high level query should produce 1000 rows. I may be entirely wrong.

Comment: Have you done the simple thing and used phpMyAdmin for example and just run that first query. If not try that. How many rows does it return?

Comment: Hi @underscore_d, thanks for the suggestion. If I run the query from phpMyAdmin, I get quit a few more records, but less than 1000: `Showing rows 0 - 539 (540 total, Query took 167.4683 seconds.)`

Comment: @RiggsFolly `Showing rows 0 - 539 (540 total, Query took 167.4683 seconds.)`

Comment: Well then the first thing is you do not have 1000 rows that match that criteria

Comment: Incidentally, LIMIT without ORDER BY is fairly meaningless And guaranty is a noun.

Comment: @Strawberry ORDER BY has been mentioned, but I don't understand why I need ORDER BY when I don't care about the order. I may be not understanding something about ORDER BY.

Comment: Can you show us the code that outputs your `Accessory data:`

Comment: @RiggsFolly I added the code that outputs my `Accessory data:`, at the bottom of my Q code.

Comment: Ok I am grasping at straws here now! I assume that the `id` column of `child_pages` is an autoincrement, right?

Comment: @RiggsFolly id is auto-increment, correct.

Comment: I would love to know what number would be reported if you added a `SELECT COUNT(*)` query above this code with the same criteria as your first query

Comment: @RiggsFolly well, the sql statement `SELECT COUNT(*) AS tally FROM child_pages WHERE scanned='1' AND processed='0'` produces a value of 256 (and is becoming fewer with each successive run of the script). So, I guess I didn't have as many records that met the criteria as I originally thought.

Comment: Each time you run this script you set the rows that you find to `processed=1` so you dont select them next run. Is this table being added to by some other process?

Comment: @RiggsFolly Yes! There is another script that runs independently, and continuously adds new records, without regard to the above script. Adds new records by the thousands per minute. I have it stopped presently, just to get a benchmark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goal is show all 1000 row in one page maybe you can load it by portions. when page open show like 100 row when scroll down using AJAX load more.

1st portion

```
$sql = "SELECT id,content FROM child_pages WHERE scanned='1' AND processed='0' LIMIT 0,100";
```

2nd portion

```
$sql = "SELECT id,content FROM child_pages WHERE scanned='1' AND processed='0' LIMIT 100,200";
```

etc...

Hope it helped.

Comment: Your answer is one of the strategies I'm considering.

Comment: As above,  LIMIT without ORDER BY is fairly meaningless.

Comment: This might aid apparent UI performance but does not answer the question of why, apparently, the query only returns 60 rows when - run standalone - 540 are available.